# How can fill I cells A1:A5 with a color using C#?

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, range

I have the following code:

```
Excel.Range chartRange;
chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A3", "R3");
```

I want to fill this range of cells with a color. I have already tried with:

```
System.Drawing.Color = "yellow"
```

but it is throwing an exception that an object reference is required.

How can I fix my code to fill these cells with a color?

Answer (score 10):

Try this:

```
chartRange.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem with your code shown above is that you can't assign the string value "Yellow" to the `System.Drawing.Color` type. Instead, the standard colors are exposed as read-only *properties* that you can access through the `Color` structure. The full list is given in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx).

Excel interop makes things a bit more complicated, because you need to convert those color values to OLE colors. You do this using the [`ColorTranslator.ToOle` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.toole.aspx).

So, for example, you need to add the following line to your original code:

```
Excel.Range chartRange;
chartRange = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A3", "R3");
chartRange.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow);
```

For more information, also consult [this how-to article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zs9xy29) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

You are directly assigning the color to the worksheet variable which Excel interop cant understand.

So you need to convert those color values to OLE values by using **colorTranslator.ToOle** method or use Excel way of coloring it. Provided both the ways.

```
xlWorkSheet.get_Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 2], xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 4]).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Green);
```

else

```
xlWorkSheet.get_Range(xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 3], xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 3]).Interior.Color = Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbRed;
```

Here **xlWorksheet** is the object excel Worksheet object.

**get_Range** takes 2 variable one start cell and other is end cell.

so if you specify both the values same then only one cell is colored.

**xlWorkSheet.cells[row, column]** is used to specify a cell.

**System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(SystemDrawing.Color.Green)** is used to define the color in OLE format.

**Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbRed** is a excel way of coloring the cells
This method gives access to large number of colors which can be found here [list of colors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlrgbcolor.aspx)