# How to programmatically apply conditional formatting on a cell range with numbers using Excel COM Interop?

Tags: c#, excel, conditional-formatting

In MS Excel you can select a range of cells and apply conditional formatting on this range. Is there a method that does it in C# using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`?

Given a range of cells containing numbers, I need to apply `Red-Yellow-Green color scale`. If there isn't a method for that, does anyone know the formula for the applied colors according to the range of numbers and the number in the cell?

[image: command in excel]

[image: output]

Comment: Does this help:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zs9xy29.aspx?  Also:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452417/cell-color-changing-in-excel-using-c-sharp

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can fill I cells A1:A5 with a color using C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871067/how-can-fill-i-cells-a1a5-with-a-color-using-c)

Comment: No no, I know how to simply apply color. I need conditional formatting

Comment: XLSGen (http://xlsgen.arstdesign.com/) claims to provide an API for programmatically creating conditional formatting.

Comment: Then perhaps this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404903.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [comment by Don](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27294985/conditional-formatting-on-a-range-containing-numbers#comment43063510_27294985), Microsoft provides a full example in C# and VB on [how to do conditional formatting in Excel using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb404903.aspx): on a given range, use `.FormatConditions.AddColorScale()` for color, or `.FormatConditions.AddIconSetCondition()` for icon set conditional formatting

As per SO guidelines, in case the link goes away, here's the essence of applying color formatting, as taken from that link:

```
// Fill cells A1:A10 with sample data.
targetSheet.get_Range("A1",
paramMissing).set_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault, 1);
targetSheet.get_Range("A2", paramMissing).set_Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault, 2);
targetSheet.get_Range("A1:A2",
paramMissing).AutoFill(targetSheet.get_Range("A1:A10", paramMissing), XlAutoFillType.xlFillSeries);

// Create a two-color ColorScale object for the created sample data
// range.
cfColorScale = (ColorScale)(targetSheet.get_Range("A1:A10",
    Type.Missing).FormatConditions.AddColorScale(2));

// Set the minimum threshold to red (0x000000FF) and maximum threshold
// to blue (0x00FF0000). Values are in 00BBGGRR format.
cfColorScale.ColorScaleCriteria[1].FormatColor.Color = 0x000000FF;
cfColorScale.ColorScaleCriteria[2].FormatColor.Color = 0x00FF0000;
```

**Important**: Color values used through COM with Excel require the color to be in `00BBGGRR` format (first byte always zero). By default, .NET uses `AARRGGBB` in the `System.Drawing.Color` classes, so *these colors cannot be used directly* (as a [mnemonic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mnemonic), the COM colors are in alphabetic order: Blue, Green, Red).

As with any Excel interop from .NET, you need to reference the Excel 12.0 Object library and import the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` namespace.