# Setting Excel Cell Colours using RGB Values

Tags: c#, .net, excel-interop

I'm trying to set Excel cells using RGB values rather than the way I do it currently as i need to set cells to a specific colour rather than a set standard colour.

This is how i currently do it:

```
ChartRange.Interior.Color = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlRgbColor.rgbRed;
```

Is it possible to set colour in RGB values in C#?

I am working with Excel sheets that have had the colours set by RGB values in VBA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can fill I cells A1:A5 with a color using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871067/how-can-fill-i-cells-a1a5-with-a-color-using-c)

Comment: @ThomasWeller Don't think so as there is no mention of working with RGB values on that question

Comment: That's true, but it shows how to use a .NET color. And you can construct a .NET color from RGB values.

Comment: @ThomasWeller fair enough

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can able to assign the `System.Drawing.Color` using `FromArgb` as below:

```
ChartRange.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I don't think that works. Office uses OLE colors, which are not .NET colors, doesn't it?

Comment: Are you sure about that, I think the `ChartRange.Interior.Color` takes an `OLEColor` value not a `System.Drawing.Color`

Comment: @BalagurunathanMarimuthu will do once it lets me xD

Answer (score 8):

You can convert from a [`System.Drawing.Color`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color(v=vs.110).aspx) using [`System.Drawing.ColorTranslator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.colortranslator.toole(v=vs.110).aspx) which will let you set using RGB values.

Something like this:

```
System.Drawing.Color color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);
ChartRange.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(color);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use of System.Drawing is no longer possible with .net 7.  Its actually fairly easy to just set the background color components like so:

(tested with C# and Microsoft Office 365)

```
byte red = 255, green = 0, blue = 0;

ChartRange.Interior.Color = (UInt32)(red | (green << 8) | (blue << 16));
```