# How to get System.Drawing.Color from EPPlus's ExcelColor

Tags: c#, .net, colors, epplus

ExcelColor.LookupColor() return string like this:

```
#FF000000
```

or

```
#FF000
```

One of them Black, second - White. I did not understand how to translate them into System.Drawinf.Color

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49599650/1315444

Answer (score 0):

You can use `System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml()`. 
You pass the #FF000000 or #FF000 string and it will return the System.Drawing.Color value.

```
System.Drawing.Color CurrentCellColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF000000");
```

Comment: I do that. Unfortunately, I do not get the colors that I really have in the file. I think this is either an EPPlus problem or a Office Open Xml problem.